# Change/restructure output of Wordpress REST API to include more data

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I want to use Wordpress as headless CMS for my single page React app 
(+axios). The website is kind of portfolio, so the photos attached to each post as galleries are the most important for me.

The WP REST API returns all necessary data, but the images links are only available after sending new request to [*.../wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=X*]. I would like to optimize it and automatically attach all image urls to regular output, so I could get one complex response.

I believe it is possible to manipulate API response, however I am not so into Wordpress.. Would appreciate for any tips and links how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to add custom endpoints, try to follow this doc https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

This is to return featured image for posts route

example posts route https://your-wp-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

```
function wp_featured_image( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    if( $object['featured_media'] ){
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
            $object['featured_media'], 
            'thegoodartisan-big'//default: 'thumbnail' or create customize sizes -> add_image_size( 'thegoodartisan-thumb', 220, 180, true ); //(cropped)
            );
        return $img[0];
    }
    return false;
}

function featured_media_posts_api(){
    register_rest_field( array('post'),//name of post type 'post', 'page'
        'thegoodartisan_featured_media',//name of field to display
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'wp_featured_image',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'featured_media_posts_api' );
```

[image: posts route request with returned featured image]

posts route request with returned featured image